# Check file extension in Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have to import data from an Excel file to database and to do this, I would like to check the extension of the chosen file.

This is my code:

```
String filename = file.getName();
String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, filename.length());

String excel = "xls";
if (extension != excel) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose an excel file!");
}
else {
    String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, filepath);
    String upload = UploadPoData.initialize(null, filepath);

    if (upload == "OK") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Upload Successful!");
    }
}
```

But I always get:

> Choose an excel file!

I can't find what is wrong with my code, could someone please help.

Comment: What value does the `extension` variable get? Great question on string comparisons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: As a rule of thumb, use `equalsIgnoreCase()` whenever you are going to check for equality between strings (assuming that you do want to ignore case).

Comment: Eeek! This code is going to throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when it encounters a filename without any dot/period.

Comment: stupid code to compare strings using != but anyway the file extension checking  code helps

Answer (score 28, accepted):

following

```
extension != excel
```

should be

```
!excel.equals(extension)
```

or

```
!excel.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
```

---

**See also**

- [String `equals()` versus `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: +1 It should actually be `!excel.equalsCaseIgnore(extension)` ;)

Comment: @peter yeah added it in answer

Comment: aha. nice trap Peter, carefully placed. it's actually `equalsIgnoreCase()` not `equalsCaseIgnore`. @JigarJoshi no, it's not 'or equalsIgnoreCase', it really _should_ be `equalsIgnoreCase` and not `equals`.

Answer (score 7):

`==` tests referentially equality. For value equality test, use `.equals`. Use `String#equalsIgnoreCase` if you want the case to be disregarded during the equality test.

Another thing: Don't reinvent the wheel,  unless it's badly broken. In your case, you should be using Apache Commons' [FilenameUtils#isExtension](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#isExtension%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to check the extension.

Comment: He might need to cut down on the dependencies for one reason or another, what he/she wants to do is such a simple thing that I actually wouldn't advice to add a dependency just for that.

Comment: @posdef, right. At least he should factor it out in a separate method.

Comment: @posdef, by the way, if you look at the source of `FilenameUtils#isExtension`, you'll notice that the task isn't as simple as it looks.

Comment: admittedly even the simplest tasks get complicated once you set out to find generalized solutions that cover all possible options. Doesn't mean that the OP needs that much of an elaborate solution. :)

Comment: @posdef Unless he's looking to make it bulletproof. In which case he will definitely need an elaborate solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (extension != excel){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose an excel file!");

}
```

should be used as

```
if (!extension.equals(excel)){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose an excel file!");

}
```

And

```
 if (upload == "OK") {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Upload Successful!");
}
```

as

```
 if ("OK".equals(upload)) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Upload Successful!");
}
```

Comment: -1 for bad code. You really want to execute `equals` on the constant, not on the variable, because your variable can be `null`. So `"OK".equalsIgnoreCase(upload)` is always better than other way around.

Comment: thanks, but your update didn't improve anything in relation to what I said above.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
excel.equals(extension)

or

excel.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Commons Api to check the file extension

```
String filename = file.getName();
if(!FilenameUtils.isExtension(filename,"xls")){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose an excel file!");
}
```

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

In my programm i did that

```
if(file_name.endsWith(".xls") || file_name.endsWith(".xlsx"))
   // something works with file
```

Comment: please provide some more details.

Comment: My example shows the simple way to check file extension. I meant you need take file name and to check that this string had needed symbols at the end

Answer (score 1):

use **equals()** method instead of **!=** symbols in your case. I mean write

```
if (!(extension.equals(excel))){..........}
```

Comment: Thanks man.
I'm a bit new to Java, so could you please give me an explanation?
I used e.getActionCommand() == "ApproveSelection" to check if the Open button is clicked in a FileChooser and it's working.
What is the difference?

Comment: @Joe88 in short == will check the reference but equals() checks the content. You can get many articles in this concept. So google it to know more.

Comment: @Joe88 generally speaking, for JVM `"ApproveSelection"` is a constant, hence ActionCommand that's been constucted with the same  `"ApproveSelection"` will internally point to the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (filename.endsWith("xls"){
    <blah blah blah>
}
```

?

Comment: Will that match my file called `fooxls`?  How about `foo.barxls`?