# Getting an error while reading an Excel file

Tags: java, openxml, xssf

I am trying to read an Excel file but I am getting this error:

> org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13].

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> ReadExcelSheetWise(String callFor,String fileName,MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception{
    ArrayList<String> colList= null;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rowList = null;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> sheetList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
    if(fileName.contains(".xlsx") ||fileName.contains(".XLSX")){
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(multipartFile.getInputStream());

    }
}
```

Note: The Excel file is protected.

Comment: [fyi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10928387/2749470)

Comment: I think there is some issue with multipartFile data. Are you able to read same excel directly?

Comment: yes,now what I have to do?